# C++ - could construction of a non-trivial pointer supplied by an allocator type throw an exception?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, exception, allocator

This question is not limited to the built-in C++11 pointer types (shared_ptr etc) but includes any custom pointer type that could be potentially defined in C++ and included as part of a standards-compliant allocator.

Could the construction of a non-trivial pointer, such as that supplied by a custom allocator (std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer) throw an exception and if so, why?

Comment: Depends on what it's being constructed from. If it's being constructed from an operator overload, anything is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[allocator.requirements]/4** An allocator type `X` shall satisfy the requirements of `CopyConstructible` (17.6.3.1). The `X::pointer`,
>   `X::const_pointer`, `X::void_pointer`, and `X::const_void_pointer` types shall satisfy the requirements of `NullablePointer` (17.6.3.3). *No constructor, comparison operator, copy operation, move operation, or swap operation on these types shall exit via an exception...*

Emphasis mine

Comment: This quote is from C++14. In C++11, this paragraph lacks the first sentence (the part about `CopyConstructible`), but the wording related to `X::pointer` et al is exactly the same.